# Adding TextView to content_main in Navigation Drawer Template

Tags: android

I'm trying to add a TextView to the content_main layout while the setContentView is at activity_main. I am currently using the Navigation Drawer template when you create a new project in Android Studio. Activity_main includes app_bar_main which includes content_main.

Content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="org.test.testy.test"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:weightSum="1">

</LinearLayout>
```

The code I'm *trying* to use is this:

```
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_main, null);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.content_main);
    //Card view create
    CardView cv = new CardView(layout.getContext());
    cv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    cv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    TextView tv = new TextView(layout.getContext());
    tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    tv.setText("Test");
    tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    cv.addView(tv);
    layout.addView(cv);
```

Everything below //Card view create was tested in a blank app, which worked perfectly fine. I also tried to put a TextView in the xml of content_main with an id and trying to read the text, which also returned the correct text. If I am able to access the layout and the code for adding to view is fine, then why is it not working?

Comment: In your second code block, you're inflating a new instance of your `content_main` layout. If you don't add that to the on-screen `View` hierarchy, you're not going to see it. That is, you're not adding `layout` to the `Activity` anywhere in that code.

Comment: So then what do I need to add into the code?

Comment: I'm assuming you don't actually want to inflate a new `content_main`, so remove all the `LayoutInflater` stuff, and find `layout` in the `Activity` just like you would any other `View`. That is, `LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_main);`.

Comment: That doesn't work it just saysAttempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.LinearLayout.addView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference

Comment: Well, then it sounds like either you're trying to do that before calling `setContentView()`, or your layout setup isn't quite as you've described.

Comment: No it's after setcontentview alright.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things I was doing wrong:

1. I had to id each of the `<include>`s with the EXACT name that it was going to and
2. I had to go through each includes because I had two:

   ```
   LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.app_bar_main).findViewById(R.id.content_main);
   ```

Comment: How do you come back to the content_main layout? I mean after we select an item from the drawer, the new fragment comes in its place. How to go back to content_main layout?